# Copy number deletion and high expression

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, copy-number-variation

I have a region that has significant CNV loss. But the expression for the genes in those regions is high compared to the expression found in the samples that don't have the regions lost. How can this happen?

Comment: Welcome. Please provide some more details 1) organism, 2) sample size, 3) how significant is the CNV loss, 4) how big is the region of CNV loss, 5) how did you identify CNV loss, 6) how did you assess whether the gene expression was less, 7) how much less was the gene expression. All of these are important if you want a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think we need to look into chromatin states as well. Thank you for the link and the pointer to the previous question.

Comment: @user438383 
I can answer some of these questions but I am not sure we can resolve this because these are computational results. I was looking at the underlying biology.